# The gas pedal stops responding after a problem with car heat

Tags: coolant, mercedes-benz, gasoline, heat

So the other day I noticed the car was getting hot and I knew it the coolant needed to be refilled. But the coolant cap was stuck so I thought I would just finish my errands and then take it to the mechanic. Bad judgement on my part of course. The car got too hot and it stopped. But that's not the issue. Later we filled the coolant and apparently there was a leakage and we took care of it.

But since then now, while i am driving the gas pedal suddenly gives up!. Even though the car isn't hot anymore. The engine keeps running fine. So I will have to switch it off and then on again and I can drive again. But another 15 minutes and the same thing happens.

What could the problem be?
The car is a 2003 E-Class.

Thanks you guys.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What do you mean that the pedal gives up? You push it down and you get no response, or limited throttle response?